How to optimize form field monitoring and automatic suggestions using MutationObserver and language APIs?
Detailed Problem Description
My goal is to create a code that reduces the number of open support tickets because currently, 33% of the tickets are just for inquiries. So, I have the following idea: when a person starts typing in the form, the AI reads what is written, goes to the database with the person's protocol number, and checks the status of the request. For example, in the form there is a summary placeholder and the person enters: "Please cancel protocol 5432." What I want to happen is for the AI to go to the database with this protocol number and finalize the requested action.
Another thing I need to implement is to enable the AI to respond at the moment someone types a question into the placeholder. It would appear with a suggestion that resolves the person's question, without the need to open a new ticket.
function resolve() {
  const fieldsToMonitor = ['#description', '#summary', '#P_DURACAO'];
  const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    fieldsToMonitor.forEach(selector => {
      const field = document.querySelector(selector);
      if (field && !field.getAttribute('data-listener-added')) {
        field.setAttribute('data-listener-added', 'true');
        field.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
          setTimeout(() => provideSuggestions(field), 100); 
        });
      }
    });
  });


  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}

resolve();

async function provideSuggestions(field) {
  let suggestionsContainer = document.getElementById('suggestions');
  if (!suggestionsContainer) {
    suggestionsContainer = document.createElement('div');
    suggestionsContainer.id = 'suggestions';
    suggestionsContainer.className = 'suggestions-container';
    document.body.appendChild(suggestionsContainer);
  }

  const text = field.value;
  if (text) {
    await generateSuggestions(text, displaySuggestions, field);
  } else {
    console.log('Field value is empty, skipping suggestions.');
  }
}

async function generateSuggestions(text, func, field) {
  const v_body = { "inputs": { "question": 'O número de protocolo enviado já está fechado?', "context": text } };

  const response = await fetch('https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/deepset/roberta-base-squad2', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer 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'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(v_body)
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  const suggestions = [data['answer']];

  func(suggestions, field);
}

function displaySuggestions(suggestions, field) {
  const suggestionsContainer = document.getElementById('suggestions');
  suggestionsContainer.innerHTML = '';

  suggestions.forEach(suggestion => {
    const suggestionElement = document.createElement('div');
    suggestionElement.style.display = 'flex';
    suggestionElement.style.alignItems = 'center';

    const robotImage = document.createElement('img');
    robotImage.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('images/robot-png_260997.png');
    robotImage.alt = 'Robot face';

    const suggestionText = document.createElement('p');
    suggestionText.innerText = suggestion;

    suggestionElement.appendChild(robotImage);
    suggestionElement.appendChild(suggestionText);
    suggestionsContainer.appendChild(suggestionElement);
  });

  const fieldRect = field.getBoundingClientRect();
  suggestionsContainer.style.top = `${window.scrollY + fieldRect.bottom + 10}px`;
  suggestionsContainer.style.left = `${window.scrollX + fieldRect.left}px`;
}

Expectations
I expected this implementation to enhance the user experience by efficiently offering relevant suggestions while filling out forms. I would like to know if there are more effective methods or recommended adjustments to optimize this functionality.
I'm developing a feature that monitors specific form fields on a web page and provides automatic suggestions when a user finishes interacting with those fields. I use MutationObserver to detect changes and a language inference API to generate suggestions based on the input text. I would appreciate feedback on the efficiency and potential improvements of this implementation.
What I've Tried
Implemented MutationObserver to monitor changes in form fields.
Utilized the Hugging Face API to generate suggestions based on the context of the inserted text.
Automatically display suggestions when the user loses focus on the field.
